# Reorganizing Lists of data.frames

Tags: r

Let's say I have a list of data frames. Where each data frame has columns like this:

```
lists$a
company, x, y ,z
lists$b 
company, x, y, z
lists$c
company, x, y, z
```

Any thoughts on how I mean change it to something like:

```
new.list$company
a,x,y,z
b,x,y,z
c,x,y,z
new.list$company2
a,x,y,z
b,x,y,z
c,x,y,z
```

I've been using:

```
new.list[[company]] <- ldply(lists, subset, company=company.name)
```

But this only does one at a time. Is there a shorter way?

Comment: are these column names or what?

Comment: In the existing list: company, x, y, z are colnames.

Comment: Why not store it all in a single data frame?

Comment: @Hadley, Technically I could but it gets too big (and slow) after a few years of data is smushed into the same data frame, with the lists I can quickly access the pieces I need, rather than having to deal with the whole set.

Comment: That's suprising unless you have millions of rows of data. Subsetting is very fast in r

Comment: @Hadley, unfortunately data manipulation is not the only task I'm running on these listed data.frames. Regardless, I've begun to appreciate working with lists of frames as it helps me identify AND isolate what I'm working on.

Comment: I'm just sceptical it's the right approach - and Chase's answer relies on the ability to put everything back into one data.frame

Comment: This particular step I should only ever have to run once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brandon,

You can use the `|` parameter in `cast` to create lists. Using the data.frame from @Wojciech:

```
require(reshape)
dat.m <- melt(dat_1, "company")

cast(dat.m, L1 ~ variable | company)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using the `plyr` package: start with @wojciech's `dat_l` and put the whole thing in a single data-frame using `ldply`:

```
require(plyr)
df <- ldply(dat_l)
```

and then turn it back into a list by splitting on the `company` column:

```
new_list <- dlply(df, .(company), subset,  select = c(.id,x,y,z) )

> new_list[1:3]
$C
   .id x         y          z
3    a 3 0.7209484  1.6247163
35   i 3 0.1630658  0.2158516
37   j 1 0.8779915 -0.9371671

$G
   .id x         y          z
2    a 2 0.1132311 -1.8067876
10   c 2 0.1825166  1.8355509
28   g 4 0.6474877 -0.8052137

$H
   .id x         y         z
1    a 1 0.9562020 -1.450522
25   g 1 0.1322886  0.584342
```

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
dat_l <- lapply(1:10,function(x) data.frame(x=1:4,y=rexp(4),
                                             z=rnorm(4),company=sample(LETTERS,4)))
names(dat_l) <- letters[1:10]
```

Code

```
Nrec <- unlist(lapply(dat_l,nrow))
dat <- do.call(rbind,dat_l)
dat$A <- rep(names(Nrec),Nrec)
dat_new <- split(dat[-4],dat$company)
```